# ReflectionException in Route.php line 286: Class App\Repositories\TagRepository does not exist

Tags: php, laravel, symfony, laravel-5

This is my class TagRepository:

```
<?php
namespace App\Repositories;

use App\Tag;
use Illuminate\Support\Str;``
use App\Repositories\TagRepository;

class TagRepository
{

    protected $tag;

    public function __construct(Tag $tag)
    {
        $this->tag = $tag;
    }

    public function store($post, $tags)
{
    $tags = explode(',', $tags);

    foreach ($tags as $tag) {

        $tag = trim($tag);

        $tag_url = Str::slug($tag);

        $tag_ref = $this->tag->where('tag_url', $tag_url)->first();

        if(is_null($tag_ref)) 
        {
            $tag_ref = new $this->tag([
                'tag' => $tag,
                'tag_url' => $tag_url
            ]); 

            $post->tags()->save($tag_ref);

        } else {

            $post->tags()->attach($tag_ref->id);

        }

    }

}

}

and this my controller

    <?php 

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Repositories\PostRepository;

use App\Http\Requests\PostRequest;
use App\Repositories\TagRepository;

class PostController extends Controller
{

    protected $postRepository;

    protected $nbrPerPage = 4;

    public function __construct(PostRepository $postRepository)
    {
        $this->middleware('auth', ['except' => ['index', 'indexTag']]);
        $this->middleware('admin', ['only' => 'destroy']);

        $this->postRepository = $postRepository;
    }

    public function index()
    {
        $posts = $this->postRepository->getWithUserAndTagsPaginate($this->nbrPerPage);
        $links = $posts->render();

        return view('posts.liste', compact('posts', 'links'));
    }

    public function create()
    {
        return view('posts.add');
    }

    public function store(PostRequest $request, TagRepository $tagRepository)
    {
        $inputs = array_merge($request->all(), ['user_id' => $request->user()->id]);

        $post = $this->postRepository->store($inputs);

        if(isset($inputs['tags'])) 
        {
            $tagRepository->store($post, $inputs['tags']);
        }

        return redirect(route('post.index'));
    }


    public function destroy($id)
    {
        $this->postRepository->destroy($id);

        return redirect()->back();
    }

    public function indexTag($tag)
    {
        $posts = $this->postRepository->getWithUserAndTagsForTagPaginate($tag, $this->nbrPerPage);
        $links = $posts->render();

        return view('posts.liste', compact('posts', 'links'))
        ->with('info', 'Résultats pour la recherche du mot-clé : ' . $tag);
    }

}`
```

And this my request:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Requests;

use App\Http\Requests\Request;
use App\Repositories\TagRepository;
class PostRequest extends Request
{

    public function authorize()
    {
        return true;
    }

    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            'titre' => 'required|max:80',
            'contenu' => 'required',
            'tags' => ['Regex:/^[A-Za-z0-9-éèàù]{1,50}?(,[A-Za-z0-9-éèàù]{1,50})*$/']
        ];
    }

}
```

Comment: Are you calling `use App\Repositories\TagRepository` on the same file you declare the class?

Comment: Have you seen similar code like this work?  I know the latest Symfony framework supports this sort of action method injection.  Don't know if laravel does.  Why not just inject the tag repository into the constructor like the post repository?

Comment: Also, make sure the path to the file matches the namespace.